# Does sql server limit the number of IPs that connect to it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, remote-access

I'v a **sql server database** installed in a windows server that I'm connecting to from a c# application.The application has 10 interfaces each one for a different user and is open in a different computer, but its one application.

The problem is that sometimes one of the computers isn't able to connect at all, but sometimes if I change the IP of the computer it connects to the database successfully other times if one of the connected computers disconnects the one that wasn't able to connect can now connect successfully.

Does the Database limits the connection to a specific number of IPs by default? or there is another reason for the problem?

Note: 
- Here is my Sql server version

*Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
    Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )*

- The maximum number of connection I get from this query

*Select @@MAX_CONNECTIONS;*

is **32767**

Modification: This is the exception I get:

***ExecuteScaler requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.***

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server? What is "can't connect", what is the exact exception message?

Comment: That exception is simply a bug in your code. You are using a connection before having opened it.

Answer (score 3):

User connections are not limited by IP address. You may have a bug in your code, or may be limited by your OS or SQL Server version (which you do not state)

> The actual number of user connections allowed also depends on the
>   version of SQL Server that is installed and the limitations of your
>   applications and hardware.

Execute this to determine the current setting:

```
SELECT @@MAX_CONNECTIONS AS 'Max Connections';
```

> Note: Returns the maximum number of simultaneous user connections allowed on
>   an instance of SQL Server. **The number returned is not necessarily the
>   number currently configured**.

Ref: [`@@MAX_CONNECTIONS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179874.aspx)

I'd suggest you post a concise, compilable code example of how you are opening and closing connections

BTW: 11.0.2100.60 is the RTM version of SQL Server 2012, which is very old!. You should upgrade that to [SP2 CU3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3002049) (it also states 'Evaluation Edition', might want to fix that...)

Comment: I've edited the question and added the version and the number of connections

Comment: I've also added the exception I get